# Suppress compiler warnings for "org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask" when not using it for connectionProvider

Tags: java, hibernate, ant

I am trying to get rid of below compiler warnings in build.log, generated by org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask.

`[hibernatetool]org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator initiateService
[hibernatetool] WARN: HHH000181: No appropriate connection provider encountered, assuming application will be supplying connections
[hibernatetool]org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator initiateService
[hibernatetool] WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : The application must supply JDBC connections`

We are not giving any connection provider or connection-url settings to hibernatetool. Instead we have specified them in standalone-full.xml inside wildfly-8.2.0\standalone\configuration using datasources.

hibernate version: 5.2.9.Final

How may I get rid of these compiler warnings generated by hibernatetool task ? Is there a way to suppress them somehow, may be using ant in build.xml ?